# why set of REST API written doesnt constitute microservices?

Tags: rest, microservices

I wrote REST API in flask using flask-restplus does helps interact frontend UI in javascript with backend in python some rest api interacts with REST API provided by gitlab and caches them and returns data to client from the cache instead.

why such an implementation cannot be classified as micro services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microservice is really a set of guidelines that help you develop scalable maintainable applications in a fast changing world. It is nothing more than that. It should not worry if you if some one else is calling it a microservice or not. If you have building some thing and you took into consideration of how to divide one big application in defined boundaries with loose coupling in between them, such that each service does one thing for you and can be build, scaled, modified independently without breaking contracts, you have followed the basic guide lines.

Microservices is about whole architecture and not just about couple of services. If you have just one service that does provide rest end points for some other monolith to consume, then over all its still a monolith, if its dealing with set of other services instead, then it may be set of services that can be called microserivces

Comment: what do you  mean by monolith consumer ?

Comment: what i meant is you have one monolith and have removed one feature out into a service and your service is being called by this monolith.